# Host not found in upstream "web" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django_project:12

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker Compose to build a multi-container Docker Django app. I have a docker-compose.yml file that sets up 4 containers: web, nginx, postgres, and redis. When I perform docker-compose build it works without error and gives me a key for my image, but when I try to run it, I get this error

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django_project:12
```

I'm new to Docker and configuration with yml at that so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    expose:
      - "8005"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/static
    env_file: .env
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_app.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8005

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    links:
      - web:web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redisdata:/data
      - ./redisdata:/data:rw
```

Project Tree

```
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── celerybeat-schedule
├── circle.yml
├── devops
├── docker-compose.yml
├── jwtAuth.py
├── manage.py
├── newrelic.ini
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── sites-enabled
│       └── django_project
├── requirements.txt
├── start.sh
└── docker_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── api
    ├── celery.py
    ├── clients
    ├── content
    ├── custom_storages.py
    ├── factories.py
    ├── ingest
    ├── media_library
    ├── page_modules
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── fixtures
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tasks.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── utils.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── paginators.py
    ├── products
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── reporting
    │   └── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── base.pyc
    │   ├── circle.py
    │   ├── prod.py
    │   └── settings_local.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── utils
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── tools.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-onbuild
```

nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM tutum/nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD sites-enabled/ /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

nginx/sites-enabled/django_project

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /usr/src/app/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8005;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Comment: The ``links`` directive is a legacy feature, use ``depends_on`` instead.